# Error creating view a when using MIN

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the script I used to create a view in Toad

```
CREATE VIEW INTERN_VIEW AS
 SELECT SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SYRISCH_COM_ID
      , SYRINCP_COM_NAME, SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE --,    
      , min(SYRISCH_CH_NUM)    
   FROM SYRISCH, SINSPL_CUSTOM.SPRIDEN ,SYRINCP    
  Where SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE = 'PE'    
    and spriden_change_ind is null    
    and SPRIDEN_PIDM = SYRISCH_PIDM    
    and SYRINCP_COM_ID = SYRISCH_COM_ID    
  group by SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME
         , SYRISCH_COM_ID, SYRINCP_COM_NAME, SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE
```

I get an error saying

> "ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias".

Comment: min(SYRISCH_CH_NUM)    as Col1

Answer (score 2):

You have to name `min(SYRISCH_CH_NUM)` as below

```
SELECT SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SYRISCH_COM_ID, SYRINCP_COM_NAME, SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE--,    
,min(SYRISCH_CH_NUM) as SYRISCH_CH_NUM   
FROM SYRISCH, SINSPL_CUSTOM.SPRIDEN ,SYRINCP    
Where SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE = 'PE'    
and spriden_change_ind is null    
and SPRIDEN_PIDM = SYRISCH_PIDM    
and SYRINCP_COM_ID = SYRISCH_COM_ID    
group by SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SYRISCH_COM_ID, SYRINCP_COM_NAME, SYRISCH_STATUS_CODE
```